# Syntax Error: Can't assign to operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this very peculiar issue in line 27: `Syntax Error: can't assign to operator`. I no idea whatsoever why it happened and I spent hours searching for the answer on this website but nothing helped. The program is in early stages of development so it would be cool if you could help me with some more issues you find:

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint

print("Welcome to a text version of World of Tanks. Choose your tank: PzII(1) T-26(2) CruiserIII(3) Ha-Go(4) M2 Light(5)")

Tank="PzII"
shoot_PzII(Tank)
if(Damage_Approved):
    print("You dealt",Damage_To_Enemy,"points of damage to the enemy.")
else:
    print("You didn't penetrate enemy armour.")

#PzII
Hitpoints=260
Accuracy_PzII_IN%=80
Penetration_PzII=49
Damage_PzII=range(9,15)
Armor_Front_PzII=30
Armor_SIdes_PzII=20
Armor_Rear_PzII=15
Armor_Front_Turret_PzII=30
Armor_Sides_Turret_PzII=20
Armor_Rear_Turret_PzII=20

#PzII Enemy
Hitpoints_Enemy=260
Accuracy_PzII_IN%_Enemy=80
Penetration_PzII_Enemy=range(29,49)
Damage_PzII_Enemy=range(9,15)
Armor_Front_PzII_Enemy=30
Armor_SIdes_PzII_Enemy=20
Armor_Rear_PzII_Enemy=15
Armor_Front_Turret_PzII_Enemy=30
Armor_Sides_Turret_PzII_Enemy=20
Armor_Rear_Turret_PzII_Enemy=20

def shoot_PzII(Tank):
    Shot_land_n=randint(0,2)
    if(Tank=="PzII"):
        if(Shot_land_n==1):
            Shot_land=Turret
            Accuracy_PzII_IN%_InSituation=Accuracy_PzII_IN%-(Distance_To_Enemy/2)
            if(randint(0,100)<=Accuracy_PzII_IN%_InSituation):
                If_Try_Damage=True
            else:
                If_Try_Damage=False
            if(If_Try_Damage):
                if(Penetration_PzII>Armor_Front_Turret_PzII_Enemy):
                    Damage_To_Enemy=randint(Damage_PzII)
                    Damage_Approved=True
                    Hitpoints_Enemy=Hitpoints_Enemy-Damage_To_Enemy
                else:
                    Damge_Approved=False
```

Comment: % sign in the identifier is a no-no.

Comment: `%` is a modulo operation -> no-no in the identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is interpreting:

```
Accuracy_PzII_IN%_Enemy=80
```

as:

```
(Accuracy_PzII_IN % _Enemy) = 80
```

which isn't allowed as you're trying to assign a value to the modulus operator between the names `Accuracy_PzII_IN` and `_Enemy`.

Just drop the percent sign for the 'name' you're trying to define, none of the tokens Python uses for common operations (i.e `+, -, &` et cetera) should be used.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.